# How to get selected checkbox based on first selected dropdown after refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, kendo-ui

I have dropdown, checkboxes and button submit. First, the user will choose at dropdown (position of work). Second, the user will select the checkbox and after that submit the data. Here, after refresh it should be appear back the previous selected dropdown and checkbox. But, I did not get it. Anyone here have more better solution?

> JavaScript Dropdown

```
//dropdown position
    $("#dropdown").kendoDropDownList({
                  optionLabel: "- Select Position -",
                  dataTextField: "functionName",
                  dataValueField: "hrsPositionID",
                  dataSource: {
                    transport:{
                        read: {
                        url:  "../DesignationProgramTemplate/getData.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: function() {
                                return { 
                                    method: "getDropdown",
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    },
                  },
                  change: onChange
              }).data('kendoDropDownList');

dropdownlist = $("#dropdown").data("kendoDropDownList");
```

> Checkbox treeview (Kendo UI)

```
homogeneous = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: serviceRoot,
                        dataType: "json"
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id : "ehorsProgramID",
                        hasChildren: false,
                        children : "items"
                    }
                },

                filter: { field: "module", operator: "startswith", value: "Accounting" }
            });

        $("#AccountingTree").kendoTreeView({
            check: onCheck,
            checkboxes: { checkChildren: true } ,
        //  select: onSelect,
            dataSource: homogeneous,
                dataBound: function(){
                    this.expand('.k-item');
                },
            dataTextField: ["module","groupname","ehorsProgramName"]
        });
```

> AJAX for submit button

```
//AJAX call for button
    $("#primaryTextButton").kendoButton();
    var button = $("#primaryTextButton").data("kendoButton");
    button.bind("click", function(e) {

    var test = $("#dropdown").val()

    $.ajax({
        url: "../DesignationProgramTemplate/getTemplate.php",
        type: "post",
            data: {'id':test,'progid':array},
                success: function () {
                // you will get response from your php page (what you echo or print)                 
                    kendo.alert('Success'); // alert notification
                    //refresh
                    //location.reload("http://hq-global.winx.ehors.com:9280/ehors/HumanResource/EmployeeManagement/DesignationProgramTemplate/template.php");
                },
        });
    });
```

> JavaScript for check checkboxes

```
  function checkedNodeIds(nodes, checkedNodes) {
  for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    if (nodes[i].checked) {
      checkedNodes.push(nodes[i].id);
    }

    if (nodes[i].hasChildren) {
      checkedNodeIds(nodes[i].children.view(), checkedNodes);
    }
  }

}

var array = [];
function onCheck() {
  var checkedNodes  = [],treeView = $("#AccountingTree").data("kendoTreeView"),message;
  var checkedNodes2 = [],treeView2 = $("#AdminSystemTree").data("kendoTreeView"),message;
  var checkedNodes3 = [],treeView3 = $("#FnBTree").data("kendoTreeView"),message;
  var checkedNodes4 = [],treeView4 = $("#HumanResourceTree").data("kendoTreeView"),message;
  var checkedNodes5 = [],treeView5 = $("#InventoryManagementTree").data("kendoTreeView"),message;
  var checkedNodes6 = [],treeView6 = $("#SalesMarketingTree").data("kendoTreeView"),message;

  checkedNodeIds(treeView.dataSource.view(), checkedNodes);
  checkedNodeIds(treeView2.dataSource.view(), checkedNodes);
  checkedNodeIds(treeView3.dataSource.view(), checkedNodes);
  checkedNodeIds(treeView4.dataSource.view(), checkedNodes);
  checkedNodeIds(treeView5.dataSource.view(), checkedNodes);
  checkedNodeIds(treeView6.dataSource.view(), checkedNodes);

  if (checkedNodes.length > 0) {

    message = checkedNodes.filter(x => !!x).join(",");

    array = checkedNodes.filter(x => !!x);
  } else {
    message = "No nodes checked.";
  }

}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCSji.png)

> JavaScript for accessing the dataItem

```
// cookies
  var values = ["LA1","LA6","LA12"]; //array nnti array ni la localstorage/cookies

    var setTreeViewValues = function(values) {
    var tv = $("#AccountingTree").data("kendoTreeView");

    document.write(JSON.stringify(tv));

    tv.forEach(function(dataItem) {   
    alert("test");
       if (dataItem.hasChildren) {
       var childItems = dataItem.children.data();
       //document.write(JSON.stringify(childItems[0].items[0].programID)); 
    }
        // document.write(JSON.stringify(dataItem.items)); 
      if (values.indexOf(childItems[0].items[0].programID) > -1) { 

        dataItem.set("checked", true);
      }
    });
  };
  setTreeViewValues(values);
  console.log(datasource.data()[0].hasChildren);
// end cookies
```

Comment: I don't know how kendo-ui works, but if you have no better ideas, you can store your values in `localStorage` for when the user returns. E.g.: `let something = myDropdown.value; localStorage.setItem("dropdownValue", something);` (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) | - | - 
| - | (Also, this question might want to be tagged with `kendo-ui`.)

Comment: As @Cat suggested;  What you're looking to do is store the `state` of your user's checkboxes somewhere.  `localstorage` and or `cookies` are common places to store them.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/set

Comment: Correct @Jim. Can you give example coding on how to use cookies?

Comment: I have a couple of questions: 1) At any point are you setting the selected values on the page refresh? (assuming this is loaded as part of a bigger view model) 2) What is the purpose of retaining the selected values after a page refresh (does the page actually need to refresh when you have submitted the form) 3) Have you considered using kendo's MVVM framework for `binding` the values to the controls? (or another MVVM framework)

Comment: I'll be happy to help you;  What have you tried to do so far?  Can you paste some code regarding storing the state of your checkboxes?

Comment: Anwer for your question @DavidShorthose. 1. I want to retrieve the previous selected checkbox based on selected dropdown (position) by user. 2. Yes, it definitely we know what we selected before that. 3. Yes, i've considered it.

Comment: if you are storing the data somewhere why not just bind the values back on the lists when you refresh the page. If you are pulling back a `view model` back to the page when submitted why not include these checked box values and then it will retain the selected values for you.

Comment: Can you show the example? @DavidShorthose

Comment: I've added the some code at above @Jim

Answer (score 0):

So without knowing how you are binding the existing values to the page I am assuming you will be calling the `page state` somewhere within your Page loading.

So I have prepared a dojo that shows two different ways of setting the `checked` state of the items.

https://dojo.telerik.com/EhaMIDAt/8

**1. Setting at the DataSource Level**

So when setting up the datasource you can add an extra attribute to your collection called `checked` this will then set the checked value for the item or children items when loaded. using the example I have in the dojo:

```
{
  id: 9,
  text: "Reports",
  expanded: true,
  spriteCssClass: "folder",
  items: [{
      id: 10,
      text: "February.pdf",
      spriteCssClass: "pdf"
    },
    {
      id: 11,
      text: "March.pdf",
      spriteCssClass: "pdf",
      checked: true
    },
    {
      id: 12,
      text: "April.pdf",
      spriteCssClass: "pdf"
    }
  ]
}
```

this will set the checked state to true for you and show the checkbox as checked.

**2. Manually Set the values after loading all the DataSources.**

So I have done this on a button click but this could easily be done on a ready state or some other trigger if needed. Here the button when clicked will find the node in the tree with the text `Research.pdf` and either set it in a checked or unchecked state for you.

```
  $('#checked').bind('click', () => {
    var box = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView").findByText('Research.pdf').find('input[type="checkbox"]');
    box.prop('checked', !box.is(':checked'));
  });
```

Again the sample it taken from dojo link above. Hopefully this gives you a start on getting the values set according to your specific requirements.

I would probably have the value checked state set when you load the datasource for the treeview.

Comment: Thank you for your sample code above. I'm very appreciate it! But, here I want it to get the previous selected checkbox or previous result that had been done by user.

Comment: So when you pull back the values for your treeview lists data sources you check to see if they selected that item previously and then apply the checked/selected state to the item. As I said in a previous comment if they are being stored in a database and a user model is being returned back to the front page with these stored values then all you need to do is bind the values back to the treeview list and update their checked state accordingly. If these values aren't being stored in a database somewhere on submit then storing them in a cookie or local storage should work.

Comment: I'm try doing it in cookie. Can you check above for the code because nothing happen as output.

Comment: The code cookie above runs perfectly with local data but when implementing it with remote data the function for tv.dataItems() shows nothing. How can I access the data from the hierarchical data for my treeview? I want to get all the id's for the nodes of the treeview.

Comment: the function that gets the remote data has that completed before the item matching occurs as if it hasn't then i would expect it wouldn't show you anything as the source hasn't bound any data yet. so it maybe worth putting this assignment task into a `Promise` or have it run after the datasource binding has occurred. It's difficult to give you an answer without a working example. From my my perspective you have individual things doing something but not really showing how they interact. I still think it would be easier to do the checked/not checked state when you are getting the remote data.